# How to create a views of channel

Tags: channel

In about us, i added different data and I want to display it in view.
How to create a view of our about us channel.
I newbie in expression.can we use the template in it

Comment: You need to use templates here. Can you let me know with version of EE you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Expression Engine is a powerful CMS that has gives you great flexibility when it comes to displaying content on a web page.  However one consequence of this flexibility is that you need to define how any / all information is presented - there are no 'default views' to work with.

The mechanism for defining these views of your content is through the creation of page 'templates' which combine instructions for how / what data to be retrieved from the CMS with HMTL information that defines the web page(s) that will be used to display it.

The way in which these templates work, and how you build a site with them is beyond what can be done in an StackExchange answer... however the EE Documentation contains two resources that might help.

First there is a [description of how the EE system 'works'](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/intro/the_big_picture.html) which is helpful background.

Second there are [some worked examples](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/how_to/index.html) of how you go about creating a simple EE site - which covers much of what you need to know to get started.

HTH